# How to make a reusable component that accepts different data for each use?

Tags: angular, angular-components

Edit: my solution was to rethink what I was trying to achieve, and instead of trying to create a component that takes parameters and a data from different sources and then gets called multiple times in the parent, I made a componet that just uses a grid layout (Material grid), then it contains all the template markup and API calls and gets called once in the parent. I think this ieasier to maintain, but not reusable in another dashboard unless I extend it and use *ngIf in the templete.

I have a dashboard that will display different lists of data from an API in an a component that is otherwise the same for each instance.

I am able to create the component and use it in the parent, and can provide basic alternatives like a header text next to an icon, but I can't figure out how to reference different sets of data from the API for each instance of the component when I call it.

How do I create a reusable component that accepts data different from the other instances and displays it using a template?

I have found some tutorials on how to reuse components, but that isn't what I need. I considered using multiple `*ngIf` in the template to test and show/hide which set of data is displayed, thus having one large component with multiple variations, but that seems messy and with many uses will be hard to maintain.

As you can see, I can change simple things like header text and icon, but the data needs a more complex structure that will not be the same for each instance.

Reusable component template

```
<mat-card class="panel">
    <header class="subheader">
      <h2><mat-icon color="primary">{{iconRef}}</mat-icon> {{headerRef}}</h2>
      <hr class="header">
    </header>

    // a table or list of data here, changes for each use. 
    // Will use for example {{ data.activity }} from one endpoint
    // or {{ data2.location }} from some other endpoint

  </mat-card>
```

Used in the parent like this:

```
 <app-resusable-dash-one [headerRef]="' Prosjekt'" [iconRef]="'assignment'"></app-resusable-dash-one>
```

reusable component .ts:

```
export class ResusableDashOneComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() iconRef: string;
  @Input() headerRef: string;

  dataRef: any[] = [];
  @Input() data: 'dataProject' | 'dataTask' = 'dataProject';

  constructor(
    public projectService: ProjectService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.projectService.getProjects().subscribe( res => {
      // assign res to data. 
  }
```

Comment: Not sure, I am able to understand your exact problem. Every new reference of the component in a template is a separate instance. So your `@Input` properties should do just fine. Also, IMO if this is a presentation component avoid making API calls from it. Rather use a `@Input` prop to pass the required data from the parent.

Answer (score 3):

In order to display or even make it editable, you have to know the data in some way. The question is, how much does your input data differ from each other?

If you have a small amount of different objects you want to display then I would create a subcomponent for each object type. You give that object to your reusable component and it displays the right subcomponent (by using *ngIf)

An other option is, that your reusable component expects a list of "attributes" to display. An attribute would represent one value of an object and a description for it. It could look like this:

```
objAttrs = [{ value: 'my text', label: 'Content', type: 'string', readonly: 'false' }]
```

The reusable object takes this list of attributes and displays every one according to the infos provided. The disadvantage is obviously, that you have to deconstruct each object into attributes - but the thing is: You have to know the data, meaning you have to know the names of the fields you want to display.

A third option is, that you use reflection. But I don't have much experience with it in Javascript nor Angular and I'm not even sure that this would work with angular binding - you have to google to find out how to make that work or if it can work at all.

Comment: Option 1 looks like it could work for me, I am trying to keep the project file structure clean as the project is quite large and is going to grow in the coming weeks. I do know the data, it comes from our own API, so option 2 is something I will look into as well. Thanks for your advice and ideas.

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for `ng-content`?

[e.g.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkjqyu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
//In App.component
name = 'Angular';
data1=[{id:1,name:'one'},{id:2,name:'two'}]
data2=[{key:'a',text:'I am a'},{key:'b',text:'I am b'}]

//And 
<hello name="{{ name }}" >
    <div *ngFor="let item of data1">
      {{item.id}} {{item.name}}
    </div>
</hello>
<hr/>
<hello name="{{ name }}" >
    <div *ngFor="let item of data2">
      {{item.key}} {{item.text}}
    </div>
</hello>
```

where hello is like

```
<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Comment: I'm looking for more separation of data in the template than this provides, as I want to call the compnent in multilpe places in the parent and also in a separate component that has a dashboard with more drill-down specific data. I wonder if I'm trying to be too clever and over-complicating. I'm keeping this in mind though, as I might rethink my structure and use this pattern instead if I can't do it another way.